# I get GPT PMBR size mismatch Error on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu

After running fdisk -l on Ubuntu I get following error

GPT PMBR size mismatch (104857599 != 146800639) will be corrected by write.

Comment: This issue is related to the partition table of the hard drive on your Ubuntu system.

The message indicates that there is a mismatch in the size of the partition table on the disk. The numbers in the message represent the size of the partition table currently on the disk and the expected size of the partition table, respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your help. As you mentioned the problem was that that  there was a modification on  the partition, but the changes was not written on the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is related to the partition table of the hard drive on your Ubuntu system.

The message indicates that there is a mismatch in the size of the partition table on the disk. The numbers in the message represent the size of the partition table currently on the disk and the expected size of the partition table, respectively.

To resolve this issue, as you may see in the output "**GPT PMBR size mismatch be corrected by write**", you need to write the changes in the fdisk prompt by pressing "w" key to commit and write the changes.